# nginx redirection from webserver to API in app server, but API is running on different ports

Tags: nginx-config

I have two web pages are running at **server IP1**

Party A  will be accessible via http://**IP1**:**10009**/web/example/**PartyA**/
and

Party B  will be accessible via http://**IP1**:**10012**/web/example/**PartyB**/

The app server is running at **IP2**

Now Party A has to access the  API from app server IP , with endpoint

http://**IP2**:**10015**/api/example/me

and

Party B has to access the same API , with end point
http://**IP2**:**10018**/api/example/me

Can we configure this in nginx ?

I have **one webserver IP1** and **app server IP2** in development environemnt, need to use nginx in demo environment

Comment: why are u running two server ?

Comment: I have one webserver IP1 and app server IP2 in development environemnt, Now I need to configure nginx for demo environment

Comment: check this link this will help for u . https://poweruphosting.com/blog/nginx-virtual-hosts/

Comment: Can you make it so the ports are the same on both servers for each client? So `http://IP1:10009/web/example/PartyA/` would access api at `http://IP2:10009/api/example/me` etc? That would make this very easy

Comment: Yes thats possible from application side, ie Webserver with **http://IP1:10009/web/example/PartyA/ **    and **http://IP1:10012/web/example/PartyB/ **Similarly Appserver with endpoints exposed as  **http://IP2:10009/api/example/me**  and  **http://IP2:10012/api/example/me**    , Can we do the ingnix configuration with these combinations?